# SQL group partitioned result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can i get unique group number (rank) for each of my partitioned result set

e.g. i need result as below, specifically group column.

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 row_num group
abc      pqr    austria type1   1        1
abc      pqr    austria type1   2        1
abc      pqr    austria type2   1        2
abc      pqr    austria type2   2        2
xyz      ppp    austria type1   1        3
xyz      ppp    austria type1   2        3
xyz      ppp    austria type2   1        4
xyz      ppp    austria type2   2        4
```

with SQL `ROW_NUMBER` function i'm able to get `row_num` column in above table.

I tried to use `DENSE_RANK` to get `group` column but getting result as,

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 row_num group
abc      pqr    austria type1   1        1
abc      pqr    austria type1   2        1
abc      pqr    austria type2   1        2
abc      pqr    austria type2   2        2
xyz      ppp    austria type1   1        1
xyz      ppp    austria type1   2        1
xyz      ppp    austria type2   1        2
xyz      ppp    austria type2   2        2
```

i need unique value for each partitioned result set as i need to perform some calculation based on group value.

can someone help to get unique group rank?

Comment: What's your existing query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be trying to partition your [`DENSE_RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173825.aspx) for group. You just need to order them like this `DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY column1 column2 column3 column4)`.

**Complete Query**

```
SELECT column1 column2 column3 column4,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY column1 column2 column3 column4 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as row_num,
DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY column1 column2 column3 column4) as [group]
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(column1 VARCHAR(10), column2 VARCHAR(10), column3 VARCHAR(10), column4 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES

('abc',      'pqr',    'austria', 'type1'),
('abc',      'pqr',    'austria', 'type1'),
('abc',      'pqr',    'austria', 'type2'),
('abc',      'pqr',    'austria', 'type2'),
('xyz',      'ppp',    'austria', 'type1'),
('xyz',      'ppp',    'austria', 'type1'),
('xyz',      'ppp',    'austria', 'type2'),
('xyz',      'ppp',    'austria', 'type2')


SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column1, column4 ORDER BY column4) AS rn,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY column2, column3, column4) AS dr
FROM @t
```

Output:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 rn  dr
xyz     ppp     austria type1   1   1
xyz     ppp     austria type1   2   1
xyz     ppp     austria type2   1   2
xyz     ppp     austria type2   2   2
abc     pqr     austria type1   1   3
abc     pqr     austria type1   2   3
abc     pqr     austria type2   1   4
abc     pqr     austria type2   2   4
```